# Is the convex combination of a convex and strictly convex set, strictly convex?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-geometry, convex-hulls

Let $S \subset C \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be two subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$, one included in the other. For the sake of simplicity, assume that they are both compact and $\boldsymbol{0}$ belongs to both of their interiors.

My question is the following. If $C$ is convex and $S$ is **strictly** convex, is it true that for all $\lambda \in [0,1)$, their convex combination
$$
(1-\lambda)S + \lambda C = \bigl\{(1-\lambda) \boldsymbol{s} + \lambda\boldsymbol{c} : \boldsymbol{s} \in S, \boldsymbol{c} \in C \bigr\}
$$
is **strictly** convex?

It is known that the Minkowski sum $A+B = \{a+b:a\in A, b\in B\}$ of any two convex sets is itself convex, but my intuition (see pic. below) tells me that (at least under the assumptions above) the **strict** convexity of just one of them should imply the **strict** convexity of the convex combination.

[image]

Comment: What happens if you apply definitions? What definition of strict convexity are you using for sets?

Comment: I meant that $S$ is strictly convex iff for all $x,y\in S$ and all $\lambda\in(0,1)$, $(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y \in \mathrm{int}(S)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true. Take $S=\overline{B_1(0)}$ and $C=[-1,1]^2$. Then for $\lambda\in (0,1)$, the line 
$$
(-\lambda,\lambda) \times \{1\}
$$
is a boundary segment of $(1-\lambda) S + \lambda C$: These points are convex combinations of $(0,1)\in S$ and $[-1,1]\times\{0\} \subset C$. In addition, $(1-\lambda) S + \lambda C$ clearly cannot contain points $(x_1,x_2)$ with $x_2>1$.